# Python smspdu outputs invalid PDU format

Tags: python, pdu

I'm working on a script that will communicate with telnet and will request sms message to be sent. Protocol which I'm using requires messages to be in PDU format converted to BASE64.

Everything works fine when I'm doing it manually using [websites like this one](http://www.smartposition.nl/resources/sms_pdu.html).

In Python i make use of [smspdu](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smspdu). I tested it and apparently PDU returned is invalid.

```
from smspdu import SMS_SUBMIT

sender = ''
target = "+48000000000"
msg = 'Hello World'
msg = SMS_SUBMIT.create(sender, target, msg)
print(msg.toPDU())
```

This code outputs:

```
010016D02B1A0E0683C16030180C0600000BC8329BFD065DDF723619
```

While mentioned website returns:

```
0011000B918400000000F00000AA0BC8329BFD065DDF723619
```

Can someone help to determine why this happens?